# Git push fail to a Windows share

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to push from my local repository to a remote repository located in a windows share.

I'm going to recreate a simple scenario, where c is my local hard disk and n is the mapped network drive, and show you the error that I'm getting.

Creating the local repo

```
user@PC-W7 /c/More_git
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/More_git/.git/
```

Creating the remote repo (as you see it's initialized without problems)

```
user@PC-W7 /n/git/central.git
$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in n:/git/central.git/
```

Then I add a new remote in my local repo, check that it actually worked, add a new file and commit it to my local repositoy

```
user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git remote add origin /n/git/central.git

user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  n:/git/central.git (fetch)
origin  n:/git/central.git (push)

user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git add a.txt

user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git commit -a -m "a.txt added"
[master (root-commit) c075576] a.txt added
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
```

At this point I'm ready to push, and here comes the problem

```
user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: File exists
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To n:/git/central.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'n:/git/central.git'
```

If I do the same steps but instead I push to a local repo in my hard disk, it works perfectly. I thought at first that maybe it has to do with premissions, but since I'm able to create the bare repository without problems.. I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm under a Novell network

**UPDATE**

```
$ git version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
```

And the output using GIT_TRACE=1 and a full UNC path:

```
user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git remote set-url origin //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git

user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git (fetch)
origin  //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git (push)

user@PC-W7 /c/More_git (master)
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-receive-pack '\''//vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git'\'''
trace: built-in: git 'receive-pack' '//vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git'
trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
Counting objects: 3, done.
trace: run_command: 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3'
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: trace: built-in: git 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3'
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: File exists
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
To //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '//vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git'
```

I also tried with GIT_TRACE and a non UNC path, the result is the same, I don't post it not to make the post longer.

Comment: can you try with UNC path instead? It's the most commonly used: `git remote set-url origin //server/share/central.git`

Comment: @CharlesB I'm getting the same result with a UNC path. See the edit

Comment: can you try to re-clone it as bare to a new location? sth like `git clone --bare --no-local . //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central-test.git`, make a dumb commit on local and push

Comment: @CharlesB what do you mean? to re-clone the already existing bare repository to a new location in the network drive?

Comment: yes, re-clone your repo to another location on the ntw share. Stuff maybe got weird with the ancient remote location, a re-clone is inexpensive and it's just to test things.

Comment: `user@PC-W7 //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central-test.git
$ git clone --bare --no-local //vshare/DATA/PUBUSER/git/central.git
Cloning into bare repository 'central.git'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

I'm sorry...I get the same problem while pushing. I think it has all to do with the Novell network.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44785/discussion-between-charlesb-and-weilah)

Comment: Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) should make the push straightforward: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41368730/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the IP address of the mapped network drive instead its UNC path or letter solved the problem.

```
git remote set-url origin //ip-address/share/central.git
```

Answer (score 2):

With the next Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), you should be able to use a path (without having to use the IP address for referencing the server)

See [commit 7814fbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7814fbe3f1e7cea1a675408df7b5dd1f5be731cc) (14 Dec 2016) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t). 
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4833b7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4833b7ec2597e65285b4d35337db48f441e9b9d7), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `normalize_path_copy()`: fix pushing to `//server/share/dir` on Windows
>
> `normalize_path_copy()` is not prepared to keep the double-slash of a
>   `//server/share/dir` kind of path, but treats it like a regular POSIX
>   style path and transforms it to `/server/share/dir`.
>
> The bug manifests when '`git push //server/share/dir master`' is run,
>   because `tmp_objdir_add_as_alternate()` uses the path in normalized
>   form when it registers the quarantine object database via
>   `link_alt_odb_entries()`. Needless to say that the directory cannot be
>   accessed using the wrongly normalized path.
>
> Fix it by skipping all of the root part, not just a potential drive
>   prefix. `offset_1st_component` takes care of this, see the
>   implementation in [`compat/mingw.c`::`mingw_offset_1st_component()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/compat/mingw.c#L2018).

Comment: I will update my Git and see if the problem is solved. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @weilah note: this Git version is not released yet: you would need to compile ti from sources to get that enhancement.

Comment: Yep, I saw it..and you said it in your post (Q1 2017). Let's see if I have time to pull and compile the last version.. otherwise I will wait until it gets published.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state which version of git (use the `git version` command). When I tried this with Git for Windows 1.8.3 (and also 1.8.4 and 1.8.5) it worked ok:

```
$ git remote add origin /z/ztest.git

$ git remote -v
origin  z:/ztest.git (fetch)
origin  z:/ztest.git (push)

$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-receive-pack '\''z:/ztest.git'\'''
trace: built-in: git 'receive-pack' 'z:/ztest.git'
trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
Counting objects: 3, done.
trace: run_command: 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3'
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 212 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: trace: built-in: git 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
To z:/ztest.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

As you can see, adding `GIT_TRACE=1` before the command results in additional diagnostics being printed which can help pin-point failing parts of the push command.

In general I have tended to use the full UNC path rather than the assigned drive letter (eg: `git remote add origin //MACHINE/Share/path/dir.git` but you may be forced to use a drive letter if the path is really long.

*UPDATE*

Checking the git sources for the reported error shows this must be coming from sha1_file.c from a failed call to `create_tmpfile` in that file. In this function an attempt is made to create a temporary file called `tmp_obj_XXXXXX` (where the X's are replaced with something unique in git_mkstemps_mode()). If it was a permissions problem you would be getting a different message so for some reason it cannot create these temporary files on the remote drive (the error is in the unpacking part where the repository is the remote one). It tries up to 16384 times to find a unique name so the problem is likely in the directory path being used. I think you will need to compile Git for Windows and get a break point in the git_mkstemps_mode function in git/wrapper.c to find out what's going on. If you follow [the installation instructions](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/InstallMSysGit) for msysGit then this will build it for you and you can try debugging.

Comment: I think it's overkill to have the OP break into msysGit debug session

Comment: I found a discussion (http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Problem-pushing-to-a-Novell-share-td7248875.html) that may be useful about what you are saying. Letting me think that it has all to do with the Novell network. But actually they don't find a solution. Should we report it to git? On the other hand @CharlesB suggested me to use Mercurial, and I will give it a try.

Comment: although I think it's a Novell problem rather than a git problem

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem having a repo on a mounted Novell network drive. For me even `git add .` reported same error as yours. Installing the new version of Novell client completely solved the issue. I hope this helps someone who comes across this problem in the future.

Btw, using ip-adress or UNC-path of the drive did not help to solve the problem.

p.s.
This is apparently a Novell-Windows-NTFS-MinGW issue only on a certain version of Novell.
Here are details, if you are interested:
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Problem-pushing-to-a-Novell-share-td7248875.html

Comment: yep, thanks for the tip. For me using the IP actually worked well, sorry that was not your case.

I was aware of the Novell problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21451629/1521115

Thanks anyway!!